# How to take each string in an array and use it in a url in rspec?

Tags: ruby, loops, rspec

I am writing a test in rspec. I want to clean up the test by grabbing all the ids from the events that were created and using them in my delete api url.

So I get an array of all my events (objects)

```
my_events = @api_actions.Get(
    'Send a request to get my events.',
    '/endpoint_url',
     nil
    )

    my_cal = my_events.result
```

Then I loop through the result array and collect each event object's id and put the ids into a new array:

`event_id_array = my_cal.map{ |event| event.id }`

Now I want to loop through **event_id_array** and delete each event using those ids, but I am not sure how to do that. I need to grab each event id and put it in the url below:

```
@api_actions.Delete(
     'Delete the event',
     "/events/#{event_id_goes_here}",
     nil
   )
```

What do I need to do to get each event id from the array to go through the delete action?

Comment: `event_id_array.each { |id| @api_actions.Delete( 'Delete the event', "/events/#{id}", nil)`

Comment: This probably not very performant.  If you simply want to delete all the records, you could have no non-restful endpoint which does that. Also, why do you want a new array? In any case, Fabio has provided the answer above.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: If the reason you're trying to do this is to clean up your database after running tests that create these records, you should check out the Database Cleaner gem: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Fabio that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the link @aridlehoover I'll look into that